# How to get TextBlob to work with all users on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to get TextBlob up and running for some teammates on a Unix server, it appears to be working just fine when I run scripts that make use of TextBlob when running as root, however when I try on the new account I create I get the following error:

```
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not found.  Please
  use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
  nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/home/USERNAME/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - u''
**********************************************************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleClassifier.py", line 25, in <module>
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.train_features = [(self.extract_features(d), c) for d, c in self.train_set]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 169, in extract_features
    return self.feature_extractor(text, self.train_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 81, in basic_extractor
    word_features = _get_words_from_dataset(train_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 63, in _get_words_from_dataset
    return set(all_words)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    all_words = chain.from_iterable(tokenize(words) for words, _ in dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/classifiers.py", line 59, in tokenize
    return word_tokenize(words, include_punc=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/tokenizers.py", line 72, in word_tokenize
    for sentence in sent_tokenize(text))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/base.py", line 64, in itokenize
    return (t for t in self.tokenize(text, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/textblob/decorators.py", line 38, in decorated
    raise MissingCorpusError()
textblob.exceptions.MissingCorpusError:
Looks like you are missing some required data for this feature.

To download the necessary data, simply run

    python -m textblob.download_corpora

or use the NLTK downloader to download the missing data: http://nltk.org/data.html
If this doesn't fix the problem, file an issue at https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues.
```

The machine we're working with is very small so I can't overwhelm it by downloading the corpora several times for different users - does anyone know how I might fix this issue? I already have it installed for root, but I don't know where the packages are or how to find them.

Comment: Did you install it in custom location? By default it goes to `/usr/share/nltk_data` and your code is searching in the same folder.

Comment: I did `pip install textblob` and it came back saying "requirements already met" - apparently the server already had it? I have no idea where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instructions in the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/data.html#interactive-installer) should work. Try setting `NLTK_DATA` environment variable and see if it works for the new user.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!